# How to get nested dict from argument_group

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I wanted different part of the program to see only the necessary args parsed.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
log = parser.add_argument_group()
log.add_argument('--name')

mp = parser.add_argument_group()
mp.add_argument('--processes', type=int)

args = parser.parse_args()
```

I'm hoping for a dict like `{'mp':{'processes'=1}, 'log':{'name'='log.log'}}`, but `vars(args)` flatten this to `{'processes'=1, 'name'='log.log'}`

Comment: `argument_group` only affects the `help` display; it plays no role in parsing.  Adding structure like this to the `args` Namespace requires a custom `Namespace` class and/or custom `Action` classe(s).  Ideas have been discussed in previous SO, but aren't simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this is not a precise solution to the question, it returns the ideal dict.

```py
class Config(Namespace):
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if '.' in name:
            name = name.split('.')
            name, rest = name[0], '.'.join(name[1:])
            setattr(self, name, type(self)())
            setattr(getattr(self, name), rest, value)
        else:
            super().__setattr__(name, value)

    def dict(self):
        dict = {}
        for k, v in self.__dict__.items():
            if isinstance(v, Config):
                dict[k] = v.dict()
            else:
                dict[k] = v
        return dict
```